# How can I repeat a failed test so that it only fails after x amount of repeats?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

We are currently developing selenium tests using visual studio and C# and using visual studio's inbuilt test runner to run the tests.  We set up schedules to run our tests through vstest.console.exe.  The issue we are having now is that periodically, tests will fail even though they have ran successfully 10 times previously.  We expect a little of that but we have stakeholders getting mail alerts to failing tests and they panic :)

What I was hoping to do was try and cut down on the false positives by repeating a failed test x number of times.  Say 3 times.  if after the test has been repeated 3 times and it still fails, then actually fail the test at this point.  Has anyone implemented this?  I have been looking around but can't find good examples

Comment: What testing framework are you using? NUnit?

Comment: We are using visual studio unit testing framework

Comment: I know NUnit 3 has a request to add *Retry*(or repeat) attribute to repeat the tests. Not sure about the unit testing framework

Comment: Thanks Saifur.  I have seen that.  Unfortunately we are stuck with visual studio for now

Comment: This answer might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374485/retry-a-visual-studio-c-sharp-testmethod

Answer (score 0):

You use try/finally statement to callback your TestMethod :

```
static int NumberTest = 3;

    [TestMethod]
    public void GlobalTest()
    {
        try
        {
            // Your failed code
            Assert.Fail(); // to remove of course
        }
        finally
        {
            NumberTest--;
            if (NumberTest > 0)
                GlobalTest();
        }
    }
```